# Filling missing dates in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like some help regarding a data frame transformation required for an analysis. My data consists of a large amount of individuals with all their historic employment. "EX" is a code representing the reason for ending employment. Something like this:

```
id  Date_start    Date_end       EX
13  "2001-02-01"  "2001-05-30"   A
13  "2002-03-01"  "2010-06-02"   B
14  ...           ...
...
```

So what I would like to do is to "fill in the gaps". This may not be easy but its even more difficult because I want it aggregated by id and each new row should have the EX value of the row before, like this:

```
id  Date_start    Date_end       EX
13  "2001-02-01"  "2001-05-30"   A
13  "2001-05-31"  "2002-02-28"   A
13  "2002-03-01"  "2010-06-02"   B
14  ...           ...
...
```

I believe the trick would be some kind of lag and aggregate but I'm totally lost.

Comment: What's basis of choosing `"2001-05-31"  "2002-02-28"   A`? How did you select `"2002-02-28"`?

Comment: Hi, the idea is to have a Date_start which is one day after the Date_end of the row below and a Date_end which is one day before the Date_start of the following row..

Comment: I do not work with dates and times much, but I would explore the `lubridate` package (it's part of `tidyverse`).  Check out http://r4ds.had.co.nz/dates-and-times.html for some help with working with date/time objects.  That won't give you an instant answer, but it might help you get more comfortable working with the data and ultimately, give you the tools needed to address it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little bit tricky, and you can mainly utilize the `dplyr` package to do the manipulation and `lubridate` packages to convert the date format(you can use `as.Date()` for sure, but `lubridate` makes it easier).

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
```

1.Creating the sample data you provided.

```
names <- c("id", "Date_start",    "Date_end",       "EX")
row1 <- c(13 , "2001-02-01" , "2001-05-30" ,  "A")
row2 <- c(13 , "2002-03-01" , "2010-06-02" ,  "B")


testdata <- rbind(row1,row2) %>% data.frame(stringsAsFactors = F)
row.names(testdata) <- NULL

names(testdata) <- names

testdata$Date_start <- testdata$Date_start %>% as_date()
testdata$Date_end <- testdata$Date_end %>% as_date()
testdata
```

2.Creating a new data set that has the data you want to add.

**id**: we are using the same id value since it is grouping by id.
**Date_start**: we are creating the Date_start with a value if there is gap, otherwise "" (empty column, and we are filtering them out).
**Date_end**: Same logic for Date_end.
**EX**: we are using the second last EX value as you stated.

```
  new_data <- test_data %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(Date_start1 = ifelse(Date_start-lag(Date_end) == 1,0,lag(Date_end)+1),
         Date_end1 = ifelse(Date_start-lag(Date_end) == 1,0,Date_start-1),
         EX=first(EX)) %>% 
  filter(!Date_start1 ==0) %>% 
  select(id, Date_start=Date_start1,Date_end=Date_end1,EX) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  ungroup()
```

3.Since we want to fill the gap days, mutate made it into numeric value, and we are using `as_date()` from lubriate to convert it into date format.

```
new_data$Date_start <- as_date(new_data$Date_start)
new_data$Date_end <- as_date(new_data$Date_end)
```

4.Combine it with your sample data and arrange it by Date_state.

```
final <- rbind(testdata,new_data) %>% data.frame() %>% arrange(Date_start)
final
```

Your final result is as below.

[image]

Comment: Hi, cant make it work because i have the following error when executing point 2.

Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `F_ALTA` must be length 9 (the group size) or one, not 300

You can find the real data here: https://pastebin.com/tqhnRUXs

F_ALTA is Date_start, F_BAJA is Date_end, IPF is id and CAUSA_BAJA is EX

Comment: It seems it does not group correctly. When I add more rows (3) with id=14. I reproduce my error with your example:  Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `Date_start` must be length 3 (the group size) or one, not 6

Comment: Hi Juan, I have updated the new_data part, feel free to try again.

Comment: So the idea is that, you don't need to reference the data frame in the mutate. However, the first argument in mutate created a new Date_start and therefore I cannot use Date_start in the second argument. I have assigned the two variables to Date_start1 and Date_end1 and modify later.

Comment: Hi and thank you very much for your help but i still get some error that, i dont understand why it happens. When i execute your code it all works perfectly but with my data it shows the following error. Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `Date_start1` can't be converted from numeric to character

Here you can use my data (only 4 columns): https://pastebin.com/aR9r9nRz

Comment: NP, I just tested it and updated my code. Basically, the if else statement first gave the "" value and the column is identified as character, but the later cell will populate number value, and that is where the error message came from. Plz try again and let me know.

Comment: ¡It worked! I learned a lot during our conversation. Thank you very much.

Comment: np. Glad it helps!